# Producing Executable for a C# project in linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, .net-core, exe

I want to know how to produce a c# executable file on Linux as when I build all I get is a DLL file in the bin folder that I don't know how to execute.
Note: I'm using vscode as my code editor and Manjaro is my Linux distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try command?

```
dotnet app_name.dll
```

Comment: This does work but I want a file to execute the program without using terminal

Comment: Then you need: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#publish-a-single-file-app) ```dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true```

Answer (score 1):

I guess a [Publish Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) is What You are looking for.

Add a file named MyPublishProfile.pubxml to your project with this content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>c21872b8-42b3-418a-ab47-103a60e7cd6c</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

save it and edit it (follow the provided links). then you can run

`dotnet publish -p:publishProfile=MyPublishProfile`

then you should have your excecutable. maybe you have to chmode it. you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)